# Multiple values for a key in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe get_tables with 2 columns

```
get_tables= df[['Database Schema', 'Database Table']]
get_tables = get_tables.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep='first', inplace=False)
print(get_tables)
dict_get_tables= dict(zip(get_tables['Database Schema'], get_tables['Database Table']))
print(dict_get_tables)
```

get_tables prints me the output as

```
Database Schema Database Table
0             abc       customer
3             abc           cust
4             def        Student
```

dict_get_tables prints me the output as

```
{'abc': 'cust', 'def': 'Student'}
```

The requirement I have is, when I do a get on dict_get_tables like `dict_get_tables.get('abc')`, I must get both customer and cust
`dict_get_tables.get('def')` should give me `Student`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want strings joined by separator use `groupby` with `apply` and `join`:

```
out1 = get_tables.groupby('Database Schema')['Database Table'].apply(', '.join).to_dict()
print (out1)
{'abc': 'customer, cust', 'def': 'Student'}

print (out1['abc'])
customer, cust

print (out1['def'])
Student
```

If need lists use `groupby` and `list`:

```
out2 = get_tables.groupby('Database Schema')['Database Table'].apply(list).to_dict()
print (out2)
{'abc': ['customer', 'cust'], 'def': ['Student']}

print (out2['abc'])
['customer', 'cust']

print (out2['def'])
['Student']
```

Anf if need combination - scalar for one element and lists for multiple values:

```
out3 = (get_tables.groupby('Database Schema')['Database Table']
                  .apply(lambda x: x.tolist() if len(x) > 1 else x.iat[0])
                  .to_dict())
print (out3)
{'abc': ['customer', 'cust'], 'def': 'Student'}

print (out3['abc'])
['customer', 'cust']

print (out3['def'])
Student
```

Comment: The approach of using groupby and list worked, but now when I try 
tables = out2(schema)
where schema basically has the values 'abc' and 'def'
I get the error TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: @Harshi - hmmm, hard to know, maybe need `tables = out2(str(schema))` ?

Comment: tables = out2(str(schema)) didn't work, but thanks for your answer

Comment: One idea - do you think `[]` instead `()` like `tables = out2[schema]` ?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is keeping a list for each key: `

```
dict_table= dict() 

for l in list:
    if l[0] in dict_table:
        # append the new number to the existing array at this slot
        dict_table[l[0]].append(l[1])
    else:
        # create a new array in this slot
        dict_table[l[0]] = [l[1]]
```

You could use such a this code above.

Answer (score 0):

dict doesn't allow duplicated keys. Therefore, to handle duplicated keys in dict you need to use `list` as values. You may use `groupby.unique` to create `dict` of list as follows:

```
dict_get_tables = df.groupby('Database Schema')['Database Table'].unique().to_dict()

Out[656]:
{'abc': array(['customer', 'cust'], dtype=object),
 'def': array(['Student'], dtype=object)}

dict_get_tables.get('abc')
Out[660]: array(['customer', 'cust'], dtype=object)

dict_get_tables.get('def')
Out[661]: array(['Student'], dtype=object)
```